# Rewrite of URL paramater not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After hours of research, reading Q&A, and rewriting my redirect code, I have not found a solution to what I thought would be a fairly easy thing to do.

I have this url
http://example.com/page.php?slug=my-page-url

And this htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

The result I would like is this
http://example.com/my-page-url

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is it producing for you now?

Comment: Nothing is being rewritten, same url as input http://example.com/page.php?slug=my-page-url

Comment: `RewriteRule` works on the URL path, and the value always starts with a slash ("/") your above configuration will never match.

Comment: Thanks you deceze for linking your response, I got my issues solved immediately after changing the hyperlinks..I wish I found that answer 4 hours ago.